# "Were I a (blank)" Is it archaic and or if so is it still proper grammar?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

A fuller example of my problem is in the following excerpts from a little thought I'm trying to jot down. I like the way it reads; but then again... any help would be appreciated.

"I'd like to believe that were I a woman and not a man, I'd have(...)

and

"To allow the crooked and foolish to go unabated could very well put my own self in danger, were I a woman."

If anybody's interested I wouldn't mind posting the entire thought for grammatical as well as creative criticism.

Thanks in advanced for anybody's input.

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what I, a native speaker, would say. I tend to think of it as the English subjunctive. But there are people on this site, far more learned in linguistics than I am, who will argue that there is no such thing as a subjunctive in English.

Comment: I don't think that one could claim that phrases such as "If I were rich" is at all archaic.  "Were I rich" is a slightly hoity-toitier version of the phrase, and in your first rendering it sounds a hair awkward.  But the second rendering is spot-on, and to be recommended.

Comment: The second sentence seems to lack enough peculiarity to, or dependency on, the unreal condition that follows. For me, *my own self* refers to the real me and preempts the *if I were a woman* bit. There isn't an obvious fix to this.

Comment: "To allow the crooked and foolish to go unabated could very well, were I a woman, [serve to] put my own self in danger" is the best I can manage before coffee. It's still a bit of an ordeal to parse.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it is right. It is a variety of what is called the second conditional used to refer to the future condition. The normal structure starts with "if I were too...". However, the inverted structure is more formal.